# ROS application chooser keeps giving me error "The parameters on the server are not set"

Tags: turtlebot, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I've just downloaded the ROS application chooser. Then I ran roscore on my turtlebot and entered the master_uri into the ROS application chooser. But I have the following error when I try to connect to the uri:

> Cannot contact ROS master: the
> parameters on the server are not set.
> Please set robot/name and robot/type

Is there a way to set those parameters? I couldn't set it in the app.

Thanks in advance!

-Bei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12128/ros-application-chooser-keeps-giving-me-error-%22the-parameters-on-the-server-are-not-set%22/) by [Bei](https://answers.ros.org/users/1434/bei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set parameter against roscore on turtlebot

```
rosparam set robot/name pr1012
rosparam set robot/type pr2
```

robot/type must be either pr2 or turtlebot, and you can use arbitrarily word for robot/name

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1